# Azure Function to Send C2D Message on IoT hub

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I am trying to trigger an Azure Function with a C# script to send a message to a device (a simple ON/OFF or HIGH/LOW). Does anyone have an such sample or can point me to such snippets?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a function arbitrarily which would send a message to IoT Hub you can simply use a sample template of [Azure HTTP Triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp) (while creating a function app on VS Code you would get a sample template) and inside the body of the function you can write a [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp) which would send the data to IoT Hub.